# SQL BETWEEN Two Columns in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

Below is an excerpt from the Laravel documentation:

> The whereBetween method verifies that a column's value is between two values:
>
> `$users = DB::table('users')->whereBetween('votes', [1, 100])->get();`

But what if I want to find out if a value is between two columns in my database?

This is my raw SQL:

```
SELECT a.*, b.name FROM restaurants a, restaurant_class b
WHERE a.restaurant_class_id = b.id
AND '$d' = CURRENT_DATE
AND '$t' BETWEEN a.saturday_ot AND a.saturday_ct
ORDER BY id DESC
```

`saturday_ot` and `saturday_ct` are `TIME` columns in my table and `$t` is a time variable. So I want to check if the time is in between the the times in both columns.

Comment: I think you have to use whereRaw method

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There is no alternative to the `whereBetween` method that applies to two columns. You can however do this in one of two ways:

**1.** Use `whereRaw` with bindings, where you use the raw condition and a binding for the variable:

```
whereRaw('? between saturday_ot and saturday_ct', [$t])
```

**2.** Use a `where` with two conditions that use the two column values as boundaries for the `$t` variable value:

```
where(function ($query) use ($t) {
    $query->where('saturday_ot', '<=', $t);
    $query->where('saturday_ct', '>=', $t);
})
```