# Return row with whereBetween

Tags: laravel

How can I extract a row according to a parameter that comes from an input to then pass the data to the view?.

I have this code but it does not work:

```
$taxableBase = $request->taxableBase;

$lowerL_and_upperL = DB::table('table_taxes')->whereBetween($taxableBase, ['lower_limit', 'upper_limit'])->get();

    return view('calculator.taxes', compact('lowerL_and_upperL'));
```

in php works me correctly in this way:

```
$lowerL_and_upperL = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM table_taxes WHERE ? BETWEEN lower_limit AND upper_limit');
    $lowerL_and_upperL->execute([$taxableBase]);

    while ($row = $lowerL_and_upperL->fetch()) {
        $lower_limit   = $row['lower_limit'];
        $upper_limit   = $row['upper_limit'];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving two variable or limit. You just gave two string array

```
$taxableBase = $request->taxableBase;

$lowerL_and_upperL = DB::table('table_taxes')->whereBetween($taxableBase, [$lower_limit, $upper_limit])->get();

return view('calculator.taxes', compact('lowerL_and_upperL'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `where()` clause.

```
$taxableBase = $request->taxableBase;

$lowerL_and_upperL = DB::table('table_taxes')->where(function($q) use ($taxableBase){
                                  $q->where('lower_limit', '<=', $taxableBase);
                                  $q->where('upper_limit', '>=', $taxableBase);
                     })->get();

return view('calculator.taxes', compact('lowerL_and_upperL'));
```

For further query, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950852/sql-between-two-columns-in-laravel-lumen) is another question answered in SO.